# Radeon Blockchain Drivers not Installing on Vega 64

Tags: blockchain, windows

I was trying to install the [AMD Radeon Beta Blockchain Drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-Crimson-ReLive-Edition-Beta-for-Blockchain-Compute-Release-Notes.aspx) onto my RX Vega 64 Liquid GPUS. The screen flickered, as it always does during a display driver install, but after my screen went black once, it didn't return. I waited for about 8 hours but it still didn't come back. Could someone help me and tell me how to get it properly installed? 
My system specs are as below:

Motherboard: [MSI X399 GAMING PRO CARBON AC](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/X399-GAMING-PRO-CARBON-AC)

Processor: [AMD RYZEN THREADRIPPER 1950X](http://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-threadripper-1950x)

CPU Cooler: [CORSAIR H80I V2](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/hydro-series-h80i-v2-high-performance-liquid-cpu-cooler)

GPU:  [RX VEGA 64 LIQUID EDITION (x4)](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1357326-REG/gigabyte_gv_rxvega64x_w_8gd_b_radeon_rx_vega_64.html)

Case:  [ROSEWILL BLACKHAWK ULTRA](https://www.rosewill.com/rosewill-blackhawk-ultra-full-tower-gaming-computer-case-8-preinstalled-cooling-fans.html)

SSD: [PNY SSD](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/pny-120gb-internal-sata-solid-state-drive-for-laptops/5900260.p?skuId=5900260) (Any hard drive that works for laptops also works for desktops)

HDD: Seagate BarraCuda 4TB ST4000DM004

Power Supply: EVGA 1000 G3 GOLD RATED POWER SUPPLY (x2)

OS: WINDOWS 10 HOME

Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: Did you follow this guide: http://vega.miningguides.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was following [this guide](http://vega.miningguides.com/) and trying to install the Blockchain Drivers.

I realized that my gpus were overheating. I fixed this problem by pointing an external fan at my gpus.